# Set initial rotation on branches

Tags: sapling-addon

I am trying to generate a Norwegian spruce with the sapling addon. I have achieved this result:

[image: Render]

The problem is that the secondary branches have the wrong starting direction. The rotation between each branch is 180 deg, so that the first branches always is in on plane. However, to get the correct result, the initial angle needs to be set to 90 degrees relative to the default value, so that the first branches is parallell to the xy-plane. Is that possible? Note: It should be easy to add a parameter to the add-on, so I could manage to do that, and also make a pull request upstream, but I may need some input on where the rotation angle is computed and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the line in add_curve_sapling.py:

```
--- bRotate = oldRotate + uniform(-rotateV[n], rotateV[n])
+++ bRotate = oldRotate + uniform(-rotateV[n], rotateV[n]) + pi / 2
```

Should make the suggestion to add the angle as a third parameter.

[image: result[1]]